# bsddb: difference between hash format, btree format, and record format

Tags: python, bsddb

I'm using bsddb in a Python script as basically a drop in replacement for a dictionary that's too large to fit into memory. Looking at the documentation for the [Python wrapper](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html), I can use either `bsddb.hashopen`, `bsddb.btopen`, or `bsddb.rnopen`, but I don't know what the difference between these formats is. I assumed that [this link](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/) to some page on oracle.com from that documentation page would give more details, but it's a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTREE is supposed to stay fully in memory. In you case you need `bsddb.hashopen`.

Checkout the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_05/html/gsg/C/accessmethods.html#BTreeVSHash) for more information.